# Portforward not working

Tags: port-forwarding

I am trying to port forward a Minecraft server. I am using MiWifi 3A as a wifi and BSNL Broadband.
I have setup the port forward but when I go to check the port forward or tell my friend to join They say cant join and the port forward checker says port is not open.
I have port forward in both MiWifi and the Broadband [This is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEw7S.png)

Comment: Can you connect to this port from local network? Probably there is a firewall on the server that blocks port and that needs to be reconfigured also

Comment: You also have to check if your internet connection has a public IPv4 address at all. Most providers don't have enough IPv4 addresses so they only provide an IPv4 address to customers that is shared or connected via carrier grade NAT to the Internet. In such a case port forwarding does not work.

Comment: @Robert I have a public ipv4 address.

Comment: @dmmedia I have allowed the port and java tm through my firewall

Comment: Can you connect to this port from local network but not from the same computer?

Comment: @dmmedia Yes I my sister is able to join me from the same network. But my friends from other network are not able to.

Comment: Can you check if port forwarding works with the 3rd party neutral tool, like for example https://www.portchecktool.com/ ? 1st run Minecraft server, 2nd configure it, 3rd try port check tool

Comment: No, it says  I could not see your service on (Public IP) on port (25565).
Reason: Connection timed out.